# Type mismatching when using type class

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass

I defined a type class like this:

```
/** Type class */
trait Drivable[V <: Vehicle]{
    def drive(v:V)
}
```

It request a subtype of Vehicle as parameter of `drive` function. And now I'm trying to use this type class to the `Vehicle` itself.

```
/** ADT */
sealed trait Vehicle{
    def drive[V <: Vehicle](implicit d: Drivable[V]): Unit = d.drive(this)
}
```

the compiler complains:

```
Error:(15, 74) type mismatch;
 found   : Vehicle.this.type (with underlying type Vehicle)
 required: V
    def drive[V <: Vehicle](implicit d: Drivable[V]): Unit = d.drive(this)
```

It works if I force cast `this` to `V`

```
def drive[V <: Vehicle](implicit d: Drivable[V]): Unit = d.drive(this.asInstanceOf[V])
```

But I hate doing so. Or, it also works if I just put it in the case class:

```
final case class Car(name:String) extends Vehicle {
    def drive(implicit d: Drivable[Car]): Unit = d.drive(this)
}
```

But imaging I have many `case classes`, I have to repeat this in everyone.

What's the correct to use this type class in the base trait?

Comment: Add `drive` as an **extension** method instead, or if it is just for an **ADT** then there is no really a point in using a **typeclass**. The compiler is right about the error, you are saying that you need an instance of `Drivable[V]` for some not yet specified `V` and you pass yourself, there is no way to prove and ensure that at call site `this` is a valid instance of `V`; is actually quite easy to create an example of how to break that.

Comment: It may help if you can describe what is your end goal and why you decide to model it like this, so we can propose a different solution or explain where was your error.

Comment: I have multiple `Vehicle`, for example I would create Car, Motorcycle...and so on, everyone has `drive` method, and of course I would provide implementations for each of them on site, but I don't want repeat this call in each case class, so I'm thinking to lift it to the trait, what's the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: I really do not see how it would be different from either drop the **typeclass** and implement `drive` on each class. Or remove the `drive` on **Vehicle** and leave the **extension** method do its job. It also depends on how you want to use your instances.

Comment: Yeah, why not just use the normal OOP way of doing things?.  Have `Vehicle` extend `Drivable`, and then implement `drive` on each subclass.  Why does `drive` need to take a vehicle as a parameter?

Comment: @RyanStull Surely I don't know what OP will answer. But with type class you can do things that can't be done with OOP. With OOP method implementation is resolved at runtime while implicits (instances of type class) are resolved at compile time. So you can do so that some of ADT types will not have instance of type class and your code can fail at compile time while OOP code can fail at runtime only.

Answer (score 3):

Either make `drive` an extension method

```
sealed trait Vehicle

implicit class DrivableOps[V <: Vehicle](val vehicle: V) extends AnyVal {
  def drive(implicit d: Drivable[V]): Unit = d.drive(vehicle)
}
```

or make `V` a type member of the trait rather than type parameter of the method

```
sealed trait Vehicle { 
  type V >: this.type <: Vehicle
  def drive(implicit d: Drivable[V]): Unit = d.drive(this)
}

case class Bus() extends Vehicle {
  override type V = Bus
}
case class Car() extends Vehicle {
  override type V = Car
}
```

---

Type `V` can be generated automatically:

```
//libraryDependencies += "com.github.dmytromitin" %% "auxify-macros" % "0.8" 
import com.github.dmytromitin.auxify.macros.self 

@self sealed trait Vehicle { 
  def drive(implicit d: Drivable[Self]): Unit = d.drive(this) 
} 

@self case class Bus() extends Vehicle 
@self case class Car() extends Vehicle
```

Comment: Interesting! it works! however the `override` looks not very beautiful, but it makes sense theoretically.

Comment: And the `implicit` one is better. Thanks @Dmytro